# When I set the image to IBImageView, get build failed

Tags: ios, storyboard, ibdesignable

My IBImageView is like this:

In `LMLCommonIBImageView.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface LMLCommonIBImageView : UIImageView

@property (nonatomic, assign)IBInspectable CGFloat borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBInspectable UIColor *borderColor;

@property (nonatomic, assign)IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;

@end
```

In `LMLCommonIBImageView.m` file:

```
#import "LMLCommonIBImageView.h"

@implementation LMLCommonIBImageView


- (void)setBorderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth {

    if (borderWidth < 0) return;

    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
}

- (void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor {

    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
}


- (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius {

    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> IBDesignables Build failed

[image]

Comment: clean project and then In storyboard go to Editor menu and do Refresh All Views; wait for build to be completed and errors should be gone.

Comment: @KKRocks, Thank you sir, you save my day.

Comment: Welcome.......@qg_java

Comment: is this working ? so do accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1. clean project .
2. then In storyboard go to Editor menu and do Refresh All Views; wait for build to be completed .