# GMstepper build failed Swift

Tags: ios, xcode

Before this happened I have downloaded GMstepper library and put it in the project folder then I used UIVIEW and then make the class of it to GMstepper and this happened.

[image: THIS HAPPENED]

Answer (score 1):

It is going to failed because the variables of IBInspectable are used in someone else IBDesignable class

I gave different name to my class clean project .then Select storyboard go to Editor menu and do Refresh All Views or else select Automatic Refresh view; wait for build to be completed

for more info please check [IBDesignable Build Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936991/ibdesignable-build-failed)