# @IBDesignable preview in IB again broken under XCode 14.2 on M2?

Tags: xcode, regression, dlopen, ibinspectable

I receive the error:

> .../Base.lproj/MainMenu.xib Failed to render instance of : dlopen(....app, 0x0001): tried: '/...' (no such file), '....app' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS....app' (no such file), '....app' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))`
> when loading my .xib. Where <MyView> stands for the name of my derivated NSView and the ... for my application name.

There are quite a number of reports with this or a similar issues when the 1st M1 processors were on the market as:
([Xcode 12 Apple M1 arm64 - Designable error: "wrong architecture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285424/xcode-12-apple-m1-arm64-designable-error-wrong-architecture)) or
([IBDesignable Build Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936991/ibdesignable-build-failed)) and more. Most of them add some pathes to the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS under "Linking".

None of the solutions given there were helpful for me, but I found a link where you could change the arch under which the Terminal should run.
[see](https://vineethbharadwaj.medium.com/m1-mac-switching-terminal-between-x86-64-and-arm64-e45f324184d9)

**Partly solved:**
Now after opening my .proj file and when I receive this error, I open the Terminal.app, switch it to Intel and then back to Arm (leaving the terminal window open) and voila the IB preview displays correctly. [See result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvMnq.jpg)

Concerning XCode this is a regression, since under Intel Xcode 11 this always was working correctly.

Anybody knows, what is happening or how to avoid this inconvenience?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found that the last part of the message with

> mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64')

is the important part of the error message.

It really seams to be a regression of XCode 14.3. My previously written workaround is not working anymore with the latest OS update, but a solution working for me was given by Robert Fogash in the

[Xcode 12 Apple M1 arm64 - Designable error: "wrong architecture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285424/xcode-12-apple-m1-arm64-designable-error-wrong-architecture)

thread. It is not sufficient to set the **Build Active Architecture Only** flag, but you should also set the debug architecture explicitly!

[This now is my working build setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdlHg.jpg). Please pay attention that still you need to stop and re-start XCode to be effective.

Comment: Xcode 15.3 and I still have this problem with IBDesignables. Your build settings did fix the problem! Apart from restarting Xcode, don't forget to clean derived data also.